# If every person clinks glasses exactly once

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that 8 people raise their glasses in a toast. If every person clinks glasses exactly once with everyone else, how many clinks will there be? Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: $7+6+5+4+3+2+1$

Comment: Hint: Clinking glasses with someone can be considered the same as shaking hands with that person.  The "handshake problem" is a famous one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to think about it is:

1st one does 7 toasts

2nd one does 6

3rd one does 5

4th one does 4

5th one does 3

6th one does 2

7th one does 1

8th one already toasted with everyone also so he does 0 toasts.

So the total is $7+6+5+4+3+2+1=28$.